# Using type #define values for division in C

Tags: c, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this integer division yield 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820865/why-does-this-integer-division-yield-0)

I have a C header file,which contains various constant values used in my project.The values are defined using #define (e.g. #define MAX_DATA_VAL 5).

When I use this value in another file for division,I get the wrong answer.

```
//- In file MyParameters.h
#define MAX_DATA_VAL  5
#define MIN_DATA_VAL -5



// - In file MyFunctions.c

#include "MyParameters.h"

void Function()
{
   float temp = 0;

   temp = 2/MAX_DATA_VAL;  // Wrong Output
}
```

The value of temp remains 0 (checked while debugging).However if I did:

```
temp     = 0;
float a  = MAX_DATA_VAL;

temp = 2/MAX_DATA_VAL;  // Correct Output
```

I get the right answer!!...Could anyone please explain what's happening...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX_DATA_VAL is being treated as an integer and thus your division was doing integer division (rounds down to nearest whole number). To make sure it knows it's a float, do:

```
#define MAX_DATA_VAL 5.0f
```

Comment: Actually, `5.` is enough, you don't need the trailing 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and the value information...problem solved :)

Comment: @Saed No problem, you should select it as a correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the defined value to a float, otherwise it is a integer.

```
void Function()
{
   float temp = 0;

   temp = 2 / (float)MAX_DATA_VAL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
temp = 2/MAX_DATA_VAL;
```

you are dividing an int by an int, therefore the result is an int - probably not what you want. To get the right result you should do

```
 temp = 2.0/MAX_DATA_VAL;
```

I saw that the other answers all suggested changing the define of MAX_DATA_VAL. However, I would advise against this, unless you checked your entire codebase and made sure that you are not depending on it being an int. My solution only makes a change at the place where OP said his results were not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In computer world, `2/5 == 0` because of integer division.

2 and 5 are both integers, so its natural for the computer to think that the result is also an integer. Unfortunately mathematically it's not, so it truncates off the remainder.